# Is Islam or Muslims anti-Semitic?

Tags: quran, sharia, muslim-practices, jews

Recently watched Schindler's list(1993), and I've been scarred for life.How did the world let this happen? How did Muslims let this happen? Aren't we Muslims supposed to be a blessing to this world?
I got to know that the movie was banned in a lot of Muslim majority countries just because it was too sympathetic to Jews. What was the stand of the then-Muslims during the holocaust? What should have been an ideal Muslim's stand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Islam isn't and a muslim shouldn't be. We believe there are good people and bad people in every nation, but we should do our best to all people.

```
(21:107) And We have not sent you, [O Muhammad], except as a mercy to the worlds.
```

This should be our standard approach. Mercy, love and understanding!

> (3:113) They are not [all] the same; **among** the People of the Scripture is a community standing [in obedience], reciting the verses of Allah during periods of the night and prostrating [in prayer].
>   (114) They believe in Allah and the Last Day, and they enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong and hasten to good deeds. **And those are among the righteous.**
>   (115) **And whatever good they do - never will it be removed from them**. And Allah is Knowing of the righteous.

We should get to know each other and try to understand and respect each other and cooperate to make the world a better place. In such conditions no hatred is allowed.

> O you who have believed, do not violate the rites of Allah or [the
>   sanctity of] the sacred month or [neglect the marking of] the
>   sacrificial animals and garlanding [them] or [violate the safety of]
>   those coming to the Sacred House seeking bounty from their Lord and
>   [His] approval. But when you come out of ihram, then [you may] hunt.
>   **And do not let the hatred of a people for having obstructed you from
>   al-Masjid al-Haram lead you to transgress. And cooperate in
>   righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression.**
>   And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty.

Al-Hujurat:

> (11) O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another] people;
>   perhaps they may be better than them; nor let women ridicule [other]
>   women; perhaps they may be better than them. And do not insult one
>   another and do not call each other by [offensive] nicknames. Wretched
>   is the name of disobedience after [one's] faith. And whoever does not
>   repent - then it is those who are the wrongdoers.
>
> (13) O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made
>   **you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most
>   noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you**.
>   Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted.

Surat Fussaliat:

> (34) Nor can goodness and Evil be equal. Repel (Evil) with what is better: Then will he between whom and thee was hatred become as it were thy friend and intimate!
>   (35) And no one will be granted such goodness except those who exercise patience and self-restraint,- none but persons of the greatest good fortune.
>   (36) And if there comes to you from Satan an evil suggestion, then seek refuge in Allah . Indeed, He is the Hearing, the Knowing.

Some hadiths about the matter:

> وعنه قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏:‏ والذي نفسي بيده لا تدخلوا الجنة حتى تؤمنوا ولا تؤمنوا حتى تحابوا أولا أدلكم على شيء إذا فعلتموه تحاببتم‏:‏ أفشوا السلام بينكم ‏(‏‏(‏ رواه مسلم‏)‏‏)‏ ‏.‏
>
> "The Messenger of Allah (saw) said: 'By the One in whose Hand is my
>   soul! You will not enter Paradise until you believe, and you will not
>   (truly) believe until you love one another. Shall I not tell you of
>   something which, if you do it, you will love one another? Spread peace
>   among yourselves.'"
>
> "The merciful (people) are shown mercy by the Merciful (Allah). Be merciful on the earth,
>   and you will be shown mercy from Who is above the heavens.... ([link](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/30))

There are many more hadiths and verses in the Quran about this.

### Conslusion

As I said, Islam doesn't teach any kind of hatred or murder. About the movie: "Schindler's list". What happened that time is one the most saddest event in our history as humans.

About your statement: *"I got to know that the movie was banned in a lot of Muslim majority countries just because it was too sympathetic to Jews"*
**Could you provide a list of countries or reference to this?**

This might be a bit off topic but as we know morocco as a musilm country:
Quoting:

> Nonetheless, before his death in 1999, King Hassan tried to protect
>   the Jewish population, and at present Morocco has one of the most
>   tolerant environments for Jews in the Arab world. [Source](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/anti-semitism/morocjews.html)

More about that:

> One participant, for example, refers to historians as authorised specialists by stating: ‘It is well known to historians that **the king Mohamed V has replied to Vichy when he was asked to deliver Moroccan Jewish leaders to the Nazi regime as followed: ‘There are no Moroccan Jews, but only Moroccans.**’ *[Comment of Moroccan on Marc Perelman, Forward, 15 December 2007.]*

Meaning he wanted to protect the Jews in his country, and didn't call them Jews though he know they were Jews. This statement really meant: *"You can dream about it, I will neither send you a Moroccan or Jew".*
Also, this is well known by the Moroccans.

Comment: quoting imdB.com "The film was banned in several Muslim-majority nations, including Malaysia, Indonesia, Lebanon and Egypt. The general excuse for the bans was that the film was unfair towards Germans (meaning Nazis) and overly sympathetic to Jews. Neo-Nazis in Western countries, including the U.S. and Canada, campaigned for the film to be banned there but were entirely ignored."

Comment: i found this article which might be good to read about the bans:
http://www.nytimes.com/1994/04/07/movies/islamic-nations-move-to-keep-out-schindler-s-list.html

Also, there are other movies like "Anne Franks Diary" which also is a movie which remind you about the terrible history. You might want to watch it if you haven't. That movie seems not to have been banned (the book was banned in Lebanon)... So the question that is left, why did some countries ban that movie but not other related movies? I am not sure.